# Can't boot up mac stuck in 'No Bootable Device error' Mac Book Pro Late 2011

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, bootcamp, startup

I have a MacBook Pro 13-Inch Late 2011 (MacbookPro 8,1) with Bootcamp installed.I have been using Mac OS High Sierra and Windows 10. Once When I boot into Windows 10, an error shows up 'No Bootable Device — Insert Boot Disk and Press Any Key'. Then I have tried to change the startup disk, enter into recovery mode, safe mode, inserted Mac OS bootable disk ,Windows bootable disk. **Nothing worked and I have even removed the Hard disk**.Still stuck on the same error. I can't do anything on my MBP. I **have tried all the startup key combinations and none of that worked** with both inbuilt keyboard and external keyboard.

I would like to fix this MBP but Holding option key for changing startup disk or holding other key combination for Recovery doesn't work on internal keyboard or external keyboard.

What are the next steps to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Does  fix mean hold the option key to boot to  macOS?

Comment: Holding option key for changing startup disk or holding other key combination for Recovery doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

This is a rare case when no keyboard works to enter the test / reset / restore screens one of two things is happening.

1. The Main logic board is not able to process keyboard input from any source - you need a repair to the internals.
2. The USB bus that sends keyboard signals is broken or the physical keyboard is issuing key down commands so fast that the processing is unable to read legitimate key presses. You need a repair to the internals.

Both paths lead to a hardware issue if you can't bring an external USB keyboard to get the system to let you attempt to choose an OS or start internet recovery. There's no third way to get in since you would need the OS to boot and a network to ssh in via a working system and keyboard.

Comment: Is that why I can't see any keyboard lights flashes even if I pressed Caps Lock key ? But Power button works fine.Is it also a keyboard part?

Comment: MBP boot into the same error even if removed the Hard disk. Why that's happening?

Comment: Hard drive won’t help figure if the USB bus or board is the culprit. in the end, not much USB you can disconnect or repair aside from the obvious external / internal keyboard and trackpad.